# For how many integers $m$, with $1 \leq m \leq 30$, is it possible to find a value of $n$ so that $n!$ ends with exactly $m$ zeros?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a positive integer, the symbol $n!$ (which is read “$n$ factorial”) represents the product of the integers from $1$ to $n$, inclusive. For example, $5! = (1)(2)(3)(4)(5)$ or $5! = 120$, which ends with exactly $1$ zero. For how many integers $m$, with $1 \leq m \leq 30$, is it possible to find a value of $n$ so that $n!$ ends with exactly $m$ zeros?

(A) 30
(B) 27
(C) 28
(D) 24
(E) 25

Ans key: 24

I’m currently working on problem 20 from the 2023 Fermat Contest.I have read the official solution but it is quite long. I am familiar with Legendre’s formula but I still can’t figure out what the pattern is to solve this problem. Does anyone know of any quick tricks or methods to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The number of trailing zeroes is just the power to which $5$ divides $n!$ so...

Comment: Compare 1,2,3,4,**5**,6,7,8,9,**10**,11,12,...,23,24,**25**,26,27,...  with 0,0,0,0,**+1**,0,0,0,0,**+1**,0,0,...,0,0,**+2**,0,0,...